# How to update multiple objects with same "key" in a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

So, I have a (unique) problem with Python currently:

I have constructor that looks something like this:

```
 def __init__(self, team, opponent, goals_scored,
                 ball_possession, pass_accuracy, points=0):
        self.team = team
        self.opponent = opponent
        self.__goals_scored = goals_scored
        self.__ball_possession = ball_possession
        self.__pass_accuracy = pass_accuracy
        self.points = points #not from csv, but rest of the fields are
```

So I decided to add the points column to keep track of points for each team.

I have two functions that do this for me:

```
    def set_victory_points(self):
        """Setter for victory teams"""
        # Assign 3 points to every team that wins
        return self.get_points() + 3

    def set_tie_victory_points(self):
        """Setter for tie teams"""
        return self.get_points() + 1
```

These functions are in turn called by main driver that looks something like this:

```
def get_victories(team_one, team_two):
    victors = []
    losers = []
    tie_match = []
    for i, row in enumerate(team_one):
        team_1 = Team(team=team_one[i]["Team"],
                      opponent=team_one[i]["Opponent"],
                      goals_scored=team_one[i]["Goals Scored"],
                      ball_possession=team_one[i]["Ball Possession (%)"],
                      pass_accuracy=team_one[i]["Pass Accuracy (%)"])
        team_2 = Team(team=team_two[i]["Team"],
                      opponent=team_two[i]["Opponent"],
                      goals_scored=team_two[i]["Goals Scored"],
                      ball_possession=team_two[i]["Ball Possession (%)"],
                      pass_accuracy=team_two[i]["Pass Accuracy (%)"])

        # Keep track of victors
        if team_1.get_goals_scored() > team_2.get_goals_scored():
            victors.append(team_1.get_team())
            losers.append(team_2.get_team())
            team_1.set_points(team_1.set_victory_points())

        # Keep track of tied matches
        elif team_1.get_goals_scored() == team_2.get_goals_scored():
            tie_match.append(team_1.get_team())
            tie_match.append(team_2.get_team())
            team_1.set_points(team_1.set_tie_victory_points())
            team_2.set_points(team_2.set_tie_victory_points())

        # Keep track of losers
        elif team_1.get_goals_scored() < team_2.get_goals_scored():
            victors.append(team_2.get_team())
            losers.append(team_1.get_team())
            team_2.set_points(team_2.set_victory_points())
```

The problem that I'm having is that I have multiple dictionaries in the list that have the same team name, but the points do not carry over from dictionary to dictionary.

For example: 
1st iteration Team A scores more points than Team B, so I assign 3 points to Team A but 2nd game Team B ties Team A, so when I go to update the objects, I noticed that Team A has 0 points instead of 3 points. I understand that this is because this time around Team A is a new object and thus will have 0 points.

My question is how would i effectively update all the "Points" references to Team A in the list of dicts so that their point score persists after each iteration?

1st Iteration - Team A has 3 points, Team B 0
2nd Iteration - Team B has 3 points, Team A 3

This is what my data looks like:

```
list=[{'Team': 'A', 'Opponent': 'B', 'Pass Accuracy (%)': '78', 'Goals Scored': '5', 'Ball Possession (%)': '40'}, ## Team One
{'Team': 'B', 'Opponent': 'A', 'Pass Accuracy (%)': '78', 'Goals Scored': '0', 'Ball Possession (%)': '60'}, ## Team Two

{'Team': 'B', 'Opponent': 'A', 'Pass Accuracy (%)': '78', 'Goals Scored': '2', 'Ball Possession (%)': '67'}, ##Team One
{'Team': 'A', 'Opponent': 'B', 'Pass Accuracy (%)': '78', 'Goals Scored': '0', 'Ball Possession (%)': '33'}] ##Team Two
```

Thank you!

Comment: Where are victors & losers coming from in your get_victories() method?

Comment: @logicOnAbstractions victors and losers are just lists, that I'm using to hold winners and losers

Comment: And do you do... what with those? They don't seem to be returned and I don't see how they are being used, other than being pilled into a list?

Comment: At any rate - in your get_victories(), of course any team will always start with 0 points at every iteration, because you instantiate a new team at each iteration. E.g. team_1 = Team(...) is a new object. For every line read in your data. And each of those objects are shiny new. You probably shouldn't have multiple Team A object created - Team A should just be one team object, that you update according to data....

Comment: For now, theyre just lists, and I was planning to put them in a csv down the road

Comment: @logicOnAbstractions how would I do so exactly?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you are confusing your abstractions. A `Team` should be an object that exists throughout and has its stats stored as attributes mutated perhaps, but not created multiple times for every single game recorded in your data. In other words, a Team object should be created once for every team in your program, not multiple times.

So I think you should review the way your divide your code with regards to the objects of interests. Here's some mixte of your code & pseudo-code about what you could do. It's not necessarily an optimal way to do it, but I'm trying to remain as close to your current as possible.

```
class Team:
    def __init__(self, name, points=0, games = []):
        self.name = name
        self.points = points
        self.games = games          # list of games that team played


    def calculate_team_result(self, games):
        """ Takes in a list of games_results & update the 
             team's statistic accordingly """

        for game in games:                          # that's one of your csv row from games_results

            if self.name == game['Team']:           # that's this team's results
                games_pts = get_victory_points(game)    # some method/way you use to calculate the points for that game
                self.points += games_pts

                # you could also update the other stats here if you want 
                self.games.append(game)             # if you wanna keep track of all the games played by that team for later use


class Game:         # your Team class was really a Game imo
    def __init__(self, team, opponent, goals_scored,
                 ball_possession, pass_accuracy, points=0):
        self.team = team
        self.opponent = opponent
        self.__goals_scored = goals_scored
        self.__ball_possession = ball_possession
        self.__pass_accuracy = pass_accuracy
        self.points = points  # not from csv, but rest of the fields are



games_results =[{'Team': 'A', 'Opponent': 'B', 'Pass Accuracy (%)':78, 'Goals Scored': 5, 'Ball Possession (%)': 40}, ## Team One
{'Team': 'B', 'Opponent': 'A', 'Pass Accuracy (%)': '78', 'Goals Scored': '0', 'Ball Possession (%)': 60}, ## Team Two

{'Team': 'B', 'Opponent': 'A', 'Pass Accuracy (%)': 78, 'Goals Scored': 2, 'Ball Possession (%)': 67}, ##Team One
{'Team': 'A', 'Opponent': 'B', 'Pass Accuracy (%)': 78, 'Goals Scored': 0, 'Ball Possession (%)': 33}] ##Team Two

team_a = Team("A", points=0, games=[])
team_b = Team("B", points=0, games=[])
games = []

for game_csv in games_results:
    games.append(Game(game_csv))


# now you have a list of Game objects that details what happened. Pass them to your teams so that they extract the data
# they are interested in from them

team_a.calculate_team_result(games)
team_b.calculate_team_result(games)
```

I'm not sure how comfortable you are with OOP programming, but your (new) Game class could have different methods to return different stats. For instance, in the Game class:

```
def get_team_points(team_name):
    # calculates if the team_name has won, tied or lost & returns the number of points
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much. I appreciate it. For now, I ended up creating 3 dictionaries, one for winners and one for tied, and made a "total points" dictionary which took  team_name and # of points . I calculated the occurences of countries and then multiplied the points for teams in winner list by 3 and tie_list by 1 and added the point values for teams in both the dicts, and then created a dict that held team as key, and final # of points as the value in the dict. Hope that made sense!